# Interesting type-system violation in C# (in safe context)

Tags: c#, .net

The type system violation which I talk about - is when emulating unions.

Why is it allowed in safe context?

- It allows you to handle value types, as different value type - as you would achieve with:

  float f = 2.5f;
  int binaryIdenticalInt = *((int*)&f);
- It allows you to reference an object of type X, as it was of type Y, EVEN WHEN THERE IS NO RELATION BETWEEN THOSE TYPES.
- It allows you to create types which the CLR won't even load (if at least one of overlapping fields is a reference type, and at least one of them is value/pointer type - the CLR would refuse to load it). I would expect the C# compiler to be more picky about what it allows, than the CLR. not less.

So, why the compiler allow such things in safe context in the first place? Why doesn't it require unsafe context for types with explicit layout, which have overlapping fields?

I hope someone out there has an answer - because it has to be interesting.

Examples (all compiled without unsafe block, nor even unsafe switch):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct ValueUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int i;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public float f;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct ReferenceUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public string str;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Stream stream;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct CLRWontLoad
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public string str;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public IntPtr ptr;
}
```

Comment: What is "Safe Context"?

Comment: Everything not inside unsafe block

Comment: Err, do you have any code to demonstrate what you mean?

Comment: Fine, can you show some code? I guess what you're doing won't compile without unsafe context.

Comment: You can also use p/invoke in a safe context or call certain unsafe APIs (e.g. `Marshal.Copy`). But I believe you cannot use it in untrusted code. So it shows that the "unsafe" compiler switch is badly designed / useless.

Comment: You can call unsafe APIs - but you cannot treat types like you would in C (or can you?), and you cannot use non-opaque pointers. And in those cases - the marshaler is doing all the unsafe stuff behind the scenes...

Comment: @CodesInChaos: It shows no such thing. The switch is well-designed and useful.

Comment: @EricLippert For the `unsafe` keyword I could agree. But I don't see much point in a compiler switch which disallows some memory corrupting behavior but not all of it.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: The point of the switch is not to disallow all memory corrupting behaviour; the point of the switch is not to *disallow* anything! The point of the switch is to make sure that the developers are not adding unsafe code blocks to the project without adequate review. When using unsafe code, ensuring safety comes from the *code review process*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me answer some slightly different questions.

> Does using the explicit layout attribute allow violations of type safety without using the `unsafe` keyword?

Yes. That's what it's for.

> What knowledge of the `FieldOffset` attribute does the compiler have?

The compiler verifies that the `FieldOffset` attribute is not on static / const fields and that it is consistent with the `StructLayout` attribute. It does not check anything else about the validity of the attribute.

> Why does the C# compiler not detect a potentially unsafe usage of the attribute and require the `unsafe` keyword?

That's a feature. In order to be used by you, a feature must be thought of, designed, specified, implemented, tested, documented and shipped to customers. This feature was thought of. It was not designed, specified, implemented, tested, documented, or shipped, and therefore there is no such feature.

> That's an unsatisfying answer.

My advice is to not ask "why" questions on StackOverflow.  "Why" questions are vague, and therefore you often get unsatisfying answers.  "Why not" questions are even harder to answer satisfactorilly because they have the presupposition that there needs to be a good reason for the world to not be a way that it isn't.

> OK, let me rephrase. If this feature were pitched to the compiler design team, **what** pros and cons might they consider when deciding whether to proceed with the feature?

- Pro: the code can clearly be used in an unsafe manner, and so should require the `unsafe` keyword to allow it.
- Con: the `unsafe` keyword is there to prevent *accidental* use of dangerously unsafe features, feature which four decades of C has shown us that even expert programmers make hard-to-find mistakes. There is no way to *accidentally* use the struct layout attribute. Someone who uses this attribute can be assumed to know precisely what they're doing, and have a good reason for what they're doing.

In my opinion, the cons outweigh the pros here. The feature would be a very small benefit for a moderate cost.

Remember, every feature implemented means another feature on the list *not* implemented, because the budget is finite. I would not want to do this weak feature and have to cut a feature that actually benefited developers.

> Has the team considered this feature and rejected it on these grounds?

Yes. See

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/357828/using-explicit-struct-layout-causes-compiler-to-produce-unverifiable-code

Comment: Thanks! Would it be true to say that that was an unforeseen shortcoming when developing the language? (not that I criticize. everyone do mistakes, and I cannot see myself able to do anything close to the C# language)... I mean, when the feature (explicit struct layout) was developed, and if that shortcoming had come to mind - then it would have implemented as unsafe? (sorry for the engrish).. and I hoped for an answer from a (ex) C#'s developer.

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz: Your English is fine. I would not describe this as an unforseen shortcoming. C# is a language designed for pragmatic professionals; the intention was never to make a paragon of pure type safety. As others have noted, there are lots of ways to abuse dangerous methods in a safe context, but these dangerous methods are typically only called by experts building mechanisms, not line-of-business developers building business automation logic.

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz: You're welcome! This is an interesting question; I might use it for my blog.

Comment: Regarding that - is it the blog in Microsoft's site?

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz: As I no longer work for Microsoft I am no longer allowed to update my MSDN blog; I have a new blog at http://www.ericlippert.com, and I also write for the Coverity Development Testing Blog at http://blog.coverity.com.

Comment: You can perfectly believe `[StructLayout.Explicit]` allows you to only define non-overlapping layouts, which would be safe, and then accidentally define an overlapping one. Pointers (the stuff you need unsafe blocks for), on the other hand, are the things which should be obviously unsafe, so according to you logic they shouldn't need the keyword. Also, I think the tone of the answer is slightly condescending, which is really only legitimate if it at least made sense.

Comment: @John: No condescension is intended. I won't respond to further critiques of tone; try to limit your critiques to the factual accuracy of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This somewhat inevitably ends up as a circular explanation.  It allows you to use unions to violate type safety because that's what you use unions for.  It cannot omit the feature because you can't write decent pinvoke without it.  The winapi in particular is rife with unions.  And pinvoke is not unsafe, it is merely unverifiable.  C# is a pretty pragmatic language, if you want to shoot your leg off then you're entitled to.

It is not otherwise a security hole.  What the CLR truly cares about is *verifiable* code.  The C# *unsafe* keyword merely has overlap, C# code without the keyword is not automatically also verifiable.  With pinvoke being the most obvious example.  The CLR source code explains it pretty well in a comment.  From clr/src/vm/class.cpp, MethodTableBuilder::HandleExplicitLayout() function:

```
// go through each field and look for invalid layout
// (note that we are more permissive than what Ecma allows. We only disallow the minimum set necessary to
// close security holes.)
//
// This is what we implment:
//
// 1. Verify that every OREF is on a valid alignment
// 2. Verify that OREFs only overlap with other OREFs.
// 3. If an OREF does overlap with another OREF, the class is marked unverifiable.
// 4. If an overlap of any kind occurs, the class will be marked NotTightlyPacked (affects ValueType.Equals()).
//
```

"OREF" means "Object reference".  It is rule number 3 that puts the kibosh on writing truly unsafe code, unveriable code can only run in full trust.  Rule number 2 rejects your 3rd example.  That one has fundamental cooties because the GC cannot possibly guess if the object reference is valid so cannot keep the object alive.

There's more code that deals with explicit layout, it for example also calculates the minimum trust based on the trust of the participating field types.  You can have a look-see in the SSCLI20 distribution.

Comment: I disagree with this sentence: "It cannot omit the feature because you can't write decent pinvoke without it." P/Invoke doesn't require it. It requires only binary compatible types. You could build a non-union, binary compatible type (ie, the same size), and calculate the different types/values inside properties, using bit-wise operations. And of course - if you wanted faster code, with more control over memory - that's what unsafe is for (and it keep the language pragmatic).

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree.  Your scheme is rather pointless.  If C# didn't support unions then you'd have to call Marshal.StructureToPtr() and Marshal.PtrToStructure() and pass different types.  Accomplishes the *exact* same thing, just a lot of pointless copying.  C# is not just a pragmatic language, it is also a fast one.

Comment: untrue. you could pass your type to p/invoke. the marshaler doesn't care if the it is a union of int and float - all it cares about is those 32 bits which it has to copy. than - you could use `BitConverter`, or bit wise operations to get whatever type you wanted - without using unsafe code, nor `Marshal.*`

Comment: What language do you think was used to write BitConverter :)  Your assertion that the pinvoke marshaller doesn't care is not accurate, it cares a *lot* about non-blittable types.  And of course it can't get it wrong, it knows what actual type is stored in the field from the object header.  We'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: The fact that `BitConverter`, or even `Array.Copy` uses unsafe code, is irrelevant. They're there so the average developer wouldn't need to use unsafe code to achieve those things. So - still... You don't need unions for p/invoke... for the same reason that you don't need unsafe code for p/invoke - there is safe code, which does the unsafe work for you, behind the scenes.

Answer (score -3):

Oh, now you've added examples.

The compilers allows it because this code is safe. Almost everything you do with unsafe code can be done with safe code. That's why nobody hardly uses unsafe code.

C# also allows you to serialize one type and deserialize it into the other. Safe doesn't mean bug-free.

Comment: The code you have tried is the code which show the unsafe equivalent... 

Try the examples in the end... the first of them is equivalent to that unsafe code - but it compiling without any unsafe block

Comment: This code is *not safe*. It can be used to read/write (almost) arbitrary memory.

Comment: "safe" means type-safe, and memory-safe... not bug free. but these violate type-safety, and memory-safety entirely